# Tricks for questions involving finding integer solutions for a fraction which contains variables

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, problem-solving, fractions, integers

I've come across several problems which involve finding a certain number of integers that the expression *could be*. For example, here is a question:

**"There are exactly four integer values of a for which 2a+b/a-2 is itself an integer" - This is only  true for certain values of b only. For how many values of b in the range 1 ≤ b ≤ 20 is the statement true?**

My thought process so far - I'm trying to work out when there will **only** be four values which a, and so far I cannot think of anything. I've also tried splitting the fraction but that hasn't worked either.

How would you:
a) tackle this problem
b) tackle similar problems in the future i.e. what can I take away from this problem that I could apply to another one down the line?

Comment: These types of problems involves divisibility. To start, rewrite $\dfrac{2a+b}{a-2} = m+\dfrac n{a-2}$, where $m,n$ are integers.

Comment: So, for m, I could have 2a-4/a-2 = 2. But what about for n?

Comment: $n=b+4$. Now think what must $b+4$ be for there only being $4$ values of $a - 2$ that can generate an integer.

Comment: That's where I'm stuck, unfortunately, @player3236

Comment: What numbers only have $4$ divisors, including positive and negative ones?

Comment: Positive numbers with two unique prime factors have four factor (but only positive). The cube of a prime has 4 (positive) factors. But the hint about positive and negative is the key! Prime numbers have 4 factors if positive and negative are counted. But how did you know to look for positive AND negative?

Comment: $a-2$ could be positive or negative.

Comment: @player3236 - so the answer is all primes from 1-20...right?

Comment: Not exactly; it is $b+4$ that must be prime.

Comment: I'm so sorry @player3236 - I'm now slightly confused again! - Would it be possible for you to write up a full solution please to explain? I can then tick that to thank you for your kind help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to know when $\dfrac{2a+b}{a-2} = 2 + \dfrac{b+4}{a-2}$ is an integer.

This is equivalent to finding when $\dfrac{b+4}{a-2}$ is an integer.

Hence we need to know when $a-2$ is a factor of $b+4$.

Since the question ask for values of $b$ where there are exactly $4$ values of $a$ satisfying the condition, we need to find when $b+4$ has exactly $4$ factors.

Since both positive and negative factors are included, only primes can satisfy this condition (as you have observed). That is, we need to find values of $b$ such that $b+4$ is prime (but not $b$ itself).

Comment: Ahhh - I see now! Thanks @player3236!